# Source.fromIterator(...) provided iterator thread safety

Tags: java, scala, akka-stream

Should `Iterator` passed to `Source.fromIterator` be thread safe?
Official docs link would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Your graph pulls them sequentially. And even downstream, without putting in some parallelization, the graph corresponds to a single actor actually. 
Youd still be fine with any Iterator passed in, due to the above described mechanism for the source.